# EntityState.Unchanged vs EntityState.Modified with no actual modifications

Tags: entity-framework-5

Using EF5 winforms, I want to work out whether the data has changed in my context.
My problem is that EntityState.Modified will be true if DetectChanges has been called regardless of whether any value has changed.

To do this I am using the following code snippet

```
 foreach (var e in Db.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            switch (e.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Unchanged :
                    break;
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    break;
                case EntityState.Added:
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    var original = this.enumerateOriginalValues(e);
                    var current = this.enumerateCurrentValues(e);
                    if (original == current) sChanges = "No Changes";
                    else sChanges = string.Format("Was: {0}  Is: {1}", original, current);
                    break;
            }
            // build string indicating No Changes or UnChanged
            s = string.Format("{0} \r\n {1} {2} {3},{4}", s, sType, sKey, sState, sChanges); 
        }
```

Is there a better way to find out whether the context has changes?

[Update]
At Gert's suggestion I put a break in a setter property.  I found the following procedure in the call stack.
The qry.Load line is causing the setter to fire.

```
  public override void Refresh()
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                if (base.bindingSource.DataSource != null)
                {
                    var per = (Person)base.bindingSource.Current;

                    this.SaveChangesIfNeeded();
                }

                DbSet<Person> dset = base.Context.People;
                if (this.QuickSearch == null)
                {
                    this.QuickSearch ="";
                }

                IQueryable<Person> qry;
                if (this._organisationId == 0)
                {
                    qry =
                        dset.Where(
                            p => p.LastName.Contains(this.QuickSearch) || p.FirstName.Contains(this.QuickSearch));
                }
                else
                {
                    qry =
                        dset.Where(
                            p =>
                            (p.LastName.Contains(this.QuickSearch) || p.FirstName.Contains(this.QuickSearch)) &&
                            (p.Organisation.Id == this._organisationId));
                }

                qry.Load();  // Setter is called here
                base.bindingSource.DataSource = dset.Local.ToBindingList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException.Show(ex);
        }
    }
```

[update]  The break also occurs when the navigation buttons are clicked. Here is the call stack.

```
>   SBD.Syrius.DomainClasses.dll!SBD.Syrius.DomainClasses.Person.Title.set(string value) Line 537   C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(object component, object value) + 0x197 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.SetValue(object value) + 0x8a bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Binding.PullData(bool reformat, bool force) + 0x26e bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingManagerBase.PullData(out bool success) + 0x118 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.CurrencyManager_PullData() + 0x2f bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit() + 0x27 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState(int newPosition, bool validating, bool endCurrentEdit, bool firePositionChange, bool pullData) + 0xf3 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.Position.set(int value) + 0x5b bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingNavigator.OnMoveNext(object sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0x2b bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0xb6 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) + 0x237 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mea) + 0xef bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button, int clicks) + 0x48b bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0xe14 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x8c bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x14c bytes    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x681 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x57c bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x6f bytes    
SBD.Syrius.UI.exe!SBD.Syrius.UI.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 57 + 0x9 bytes C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(System.ActivationContext activationContext, string[] activationCustomData) + 0x66 bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone() + 0x8d bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x285 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x9 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x57 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x51 bytes   
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

Comment: That's when the entity is materialized. It would be interesting to see if the breakpoint is hit after the binding, just by navigating and not modifying anything.

Comment: Yes it is. I updated the question with the call stack.

Comment: OK, so the navigation does set values. That's sad (shouldn't be necessary I think). However, in (your) `DbContext` API, setting a property to its original value does NOT mark the property as changed, because `DetectChanges()` actually compares values. In generated code of the `ObjectContext` API setting _any_ value will fire the object's PropertyChanged and set the state to Modified (wasn't aware of this difference, hence my remark below).

Comment: So, to add some confusion, in your case this binding issue should not "modify" objects unless there are real changes. It looks like "some" property is always changed, either by the binding or by other parts of your code.